# first object not being added to arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have the class city which I store different properties and a method to send an `http request` :

```
 public class city {
    int temperature;
    String conditions;
    String town;
    String country;
    String state;

    public String requestData(String url) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject mresponse = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
                            cityIndex = mresponse.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("city");
                            SharedPreferences cityList = getSharedPreferences("cityList", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = cityList.edit();
                            editor.putString(cityIndex, response);
                            editor.apply();
                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return null;
    }

}
```

I then run this line of code after inputting into a textfield a zip code which takes the zip code, wraps it inside a url, and then has the url be sent as an http request inside the `city.requestData()`. The json is then stringified and sent back using sharedpreferences. The json is then made an object and then store in different properties of a newly created city object. These created cities are then stored inside the citylist array.

```
       Editable zipCode = mCity.getText();
                String API = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D" + String.valueOf(zipCode) + ")&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
                city createdCity = new city();
                createdCity.requestData(API);
                dialog.dismiss();
                SharedPreferences cityList = getSharedPreferences("cityList", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String mResponse= cityList.getString(cityIndex, "");

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mResponse);
                    JSONObject response = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
                    createdCity.temperature = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("item").optJSONObject("condition").getInt("temp");
                    createdCity.conditions = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("item").optJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                    createdCity.town = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("city");
                    createdCity.country = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("country");
                    createdCity.state = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("region");
                   cities.add(createdCity);
                    addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer(createdCity.town , createdCity.state);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("cities", cities.toString());
                i++;
```

My problem I'm having with my code is when logging "cities", the first city is never logged, and the second city is logged as what the first city should have been.

For example, If I input Kansas, it would be logged as [ ]. I then input New York, it would be logged Kansas. I then input Los Angeles, It would log out New York.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are retrieving the shared preference before the city completes it's request. Remember network requests are made in a background thread. While the city is still requesting the data, you read the preference stored by the previous city.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You are definitely right, it is definitely just unsynced threads. Should I use a latch countdown to solve this?

Comment: You are still using java, I guess the best approach is to use callbacks executed when the request is done. You may call it from "onResponse". But I strongly recommend you to migrate to kotlin :)